# How to use multiple endpoints (IN and OUT) in Bulk Mode for USB comm in PIC24FJGB410

Tags: usb, winusb

In my project I am configuring USB endpoints (Bulk Mode) for both In and Out from the Host. I'm using PIC24FJ256GB410 and Microchip example code “Vendor throughput“ configured with PIC24FSTARTER KIT.

Everything works OK if I’m using Endpoint 1, 2,3 for OUT and Endpoint 1 for IN.

The moment I configure Endpoint 1, 2, 3 for OUT and Endpoint 81 for IN.  Data OUT works Fine but Data IN doesn’t work at all.

I’m using VC++ as frontend and WINUSB write pipe use Endpoint 1 for OUT and Endpoint 81 for IN.

I’m totally confused. In general Endpoint Numbers for both Host side and Device side should match but in my case the moment I try to match it doesn’t work.

The complete code is attached for debugging and your valuable advice.

**CODE LINK ARE AS UNDER**

---

### [USB Descriptor & USB CONFIGURATION](https://pastebin.com/ZmuCjp0f)

---

### [USB DATA IN & OUT CODE](https://pastebin.com/inUyy2kc)

Comment: "The complete code is attached" - I can't see that it is. Would you edit the question to include this, please?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: My apologies for the missing code, Actually website prevent me from posting three links . So I could not post earlier. Now I have copied data and pasted in two Links.

Comment: We prefer it if code is shown in the question itself, since links tend to die off quickly. Would you paste in each piece of code, select it, and click the 'code' `{}` button? That will format it appropriately. Thanks.

Comment: The code is about 6-7 Pages if pasted could be difficult for reading. So posted as Link for ease of understanding.

Comment: Right, readers are unlikely to wade their way through that. Can the problem be cut down at all, such that the code a reader would need to see is much smaller, and could be presented here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. Well, I have been working on this code and have found something interesting which I wanted to share with readers. Please correct if I’m wrong.

I think the problem is resolved or actually, there is no problem at all.  USB is a Host based protocol so data OUT from host will be always 1,2,3,4 and IN will be 81, 82, 83.regardless of how you are sending from DEVICE. On Device while initializing USB descriptor we have done EP1,2,3 OUT and EP 81,82 IN but actually when we send/receive  , we do out thru 1,2,3 and IN thru 1,2 instead of 81, 82. The IN Endpoint conversion from 1, 2 to 81, 82 is done by USB Descriptor. Additionally on reading PIC 24fj manual I can only find 0-15 endpoints. No endpoints on the name of 81, 82 is defined. So In nutshell there is nothing wrong the way it’s working.

At This moment I choose to used EP1, 2, 3 for OUT and IN EP 4, 5, 6 (configured in VC++ as 84, 85, 86) to move ahead and all is well.